# SwiftUI: react to NSManagedObject property change in SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, combine

I am trying to figure how to have a SwiftUI view properly react to the changes made to an NSManagedObject property.

Example:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
            
    @Published var car:Car // <-- NSManagedObject
    @Published var sold:Bool = false // <-- I don't want to do this, I want to simply observe the sold property on car and not have to implement this sink logic below
    var subs = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    init(car:Car) {
        self.car = car
        self.sold = car.sold
        self.car.publisher(for: \.sold)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] sold in
                self?.sold = sold
            }
            .store(in: &subs)
    }
    
}
```

As an example, I have a Toggle that lets me set the `sold` property on the Car entity.

```
Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(get: { model.car.sold }, set: { model.car.sold = $0 } )) {
    if model.car.sold {
        Text("ON")
    } else {
        Text("OFF")
    }
}
```

Toggling the control does set the `sold` property on the car instance, but, the Toggle label:

```
    if model.car.sold {
        Text("ON")
    } else {
        Text("OFF")
    }
```

does not update accordingly.

So, if I change the car entity as a whole, things update, if I change a property of the entity the view does not update. So then I implemented the `sink` logic to then set a published `sold` property on the model. So the `sold` property on the car is set by the toggle, the sink kicks in and sets the model.sold, and then the Toggle label Text does update.

How can I do away with the additional `@Published var sold:Bool = false` in the model and simply cause the Toggle label to react to the actual `car.sold` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe Car directly, it confirms to ObservableObject, so instead of view model pass in view it like

```
struct CarView: View {
  @ObservedObject var car: Car
```

Comment: Interesting, so, @Published var of an observable object hides changes to the object's properties... This approach fixed things for me. thanks.

Comment: @zumzum yes -- if you have a nested ObservableObject you must call `objectWillChange.send()` manually on changes. Best to avoid if possible.